# Visual Studio cannot process a dimension

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssas, cube

I'm trying to create a cube using SQL Server 2008 R2. When I tried to **process** a dimension, this error occurred:

> The project could not be deployed to the 'wasim-PC/Joker' server
>   because of the following connectivity problems :  A connection cannot
>   be made. Ensure that the server is running.  To verify or update the
>   name of the target server, right-click on the project in Solution
>   Explorer, select Project Properties, click on the Deployment tab, and
>   then enter the name of the server.

I searched about a solution but I failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed **UAC Setting** to *"Never notify me"* and every thing work well now! ( Windows 7 )

Answer (score 0):

When you process a cube or dimension, its definition is first deployed to a server running SQL Server Analysis Services.

The error tells you that the deployment fails because it cannot find the service on 'wasim-PC/Joker'. I'm guessing this is your workstation. Make sure they analysis services service is installed and running on your local system. If you want to deploy to a different server, follow the steps specified in the error message.